# jQuery - wrap issue - want to declare elements

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a wrap() that is working fine, but the problem is, I need to be able to tell it where to start the wrap (by an element ID..#start) and where to end it (again, by an element ID...#end).  Is this possible?  Did I do a good job of phrasing the question? Thanks.

Comment: couldn't you just create the element with the DOM and append the nodes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really trying to wrap from one sibling to the next in a containing div, you can do it like this:

```
function wrap(begin, end) {
    var start = $(begin); 
    var div = $("<div>").addClass("wrap").insertBefore(start);
    start.nextUntil(end).add(start).add(end).appendTo(div);
    return(div);
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YFxpN/.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#start").nextUntil("#end").add("#end")
```

Or ff you want it to be exclusive, do this:

```
$("#start").nextUntil("#end").not('#start')
```

And yes, you did a decent job phrasing that question.

---

More info about the nextUntil method: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 1):

Ivan Castellanos answer is close, but if you want it to include the start element as well, you'll have to use this:

```
$("#start").nextUntil("#end").add('#start').add("#end")
```

As far as being exclusive, this would work:

```
$("#start").nextUntil("#end")
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, can you see jsfiddle.net/JMcJf and tell me why they are being wrapped in individual divs?  I just wanted one div to wrap them all...just from prices in bold to the last price listed. THanks!

Comment: The method above creates an array-like object with each of the matching elements in it.  Your wrap function is being called on each of the elements in this array-like object.  Take a look at how @jfriend00 did it below.